# Using INDEX partially to populate a matrix from a list

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-2010, worksheet-function, countif

My Excel spreadsheet has two columns: `Product ID`s and the `Catalog View` they have. Products may have several different Catalog Views.

How may I use INDEX to bring the one record of the `Product ID` and then all the associated `Catalog`s laid out to the right of the `Product ID`?

Link to the example here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXE6KdAx3STUjlQODZlS25zTlU/view?usp=sharing and screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `TOP2` is in A9, please try in F2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,$E2)>=1*RIGHT(F$1),INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($E2,$A:$A,0)+1*RIGHT(F$1)-1),"")
```

copied across and down to suit.

Comment: That did it, Thank you so much. I have watched every video out there on this function, and still couldn't come up with the correct formula. You have saved my sanity.